# parse string with tags

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, parsing

I am receiving a chunk of data from PBX in string with tags included.
Something like this:

```
</response><rid>2</rid><name>2101<name><PeerList></PeerList><status>UNKNOWN</status>
```

cont...till it fetches all the names/users from the PBX.

what i need to do is to parse this string data to retrieve name & status and update in to the table where i can add the user into iPhone's phonebook.
I've started with NSScanner but eventually i messed up with that.
if anyone has any idea please help me out!!!!

Comment: Yes forgot to mention that, provide the complete XML file and not an incomplete fraction of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have received an XML file, use an XML parser first.

What language/OS/environment are you using?

NSScanner seems to be Mac specific.

Comment: Hi Ernelli,
            i need to clarify here,this is not a XML data. This is something customized data coming from the PBX(Asterisk) over TCP. I am developing the app for iPhone 3G. Can i include the XML header while receiving the data & then parse it using NSXMLParser. The app is something like "Avaya one-x" with call control,call forward features but as i cannot use the CSTA protocols for iPhone, so i ve to settle with a middlewear server which connects to the Asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or a third-party framework such as [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML).

Comment: i need to clarify here, this is not XML data otherwise i could have settled with NSXMLParser. This is something customized data with tags coming from the PBX over TCP. Can i include the XML header after receiving the complete data & then parse the same with NSXMLParser???

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you are trying to develop your own parser. I am not sure about the best approach in that case, but NSScanner does look promising. Could you provide more details about the issue(s) you had?